# Can't access files from one program in another

Tags: files, tmp

This must be some snapcraft thing, but I can't access files in tmp and it's making me crazy. If I take a screenshot, save it to /tmp, and then try to open that file in Firefox, it's like it doesn't exist.

I did something similar where I saved a file from Firefox to /tmp, then tried to open it in Gimp and Gimp had no idea it existed.

Is there some new permissions boundary that's making my system useless? I use /tmp a lot for random files I want to lose when the machine reboots.

Comment: Snap applications are *generally* restricted to accessing files that are in your home directory only. If you would like to have an ephemeral directory that is wiped out every time your system reboots, you could look at having a script run at login to wipe a directory, or a cronjob that clears files older than a day, or even creating and mounting a `tmpfs` location in your home directory 

Comment: Hm, that must be it. Is there a way to slacken this restriction so I can see the tmp directory?